Neurobiology Rivalries, part IV, A New Hope?
This is a follow on for these 3 questions:

The neuroscience and neurobiology tags
Are questions about neurobiology on or off topic?
Splitting up questions on neurobiology between cognitivesciences.se and biology.se?

(and this related Meta.Biology.SE question)
As of late, there have been a handful of questions on Biology seem to be more "cognitive" in nature, in light of both sites' definition in the questions above as to what's on-topic in this realm.  
Brace for more bulleted text:

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/how-does-this-illusion-work
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/why-hasnt-mother-nature-made-us-aware-of-our-lizard-brain (not really a gem, but still something that could have been better here if it were constructive and/or factual)
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/how-old-does-a-baby-have-to-be-before-it-can-retain-memories
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/what-is-the-timing-of-information-assimilation-within-a-human-brain
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/why-does-a-drop-of-water-penetrate-deep-sleep
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/why-apes-started-to-contemplate-and-become-altruistic (again, not quality, closed as off topic, but still along our lines, though the evolutionary aspect of it probably belongs on Bio)
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/why-are-melodies-harmonies-perceived-as-pleasurable-by-humans (I mean who does that "jonsca" think he is??)

A couple of other CogSci users and I have placed comments and/or flagged some of these questions as potential candidates for CogSci, and those flags and concerns seem to be accepted, but nothing further was ever done about it.  Biology is slightly older than we are, they've got a slightly larger user base, and I'm sure they need to hold onto all of the questions they can, just like we do here, but if a question will get a better answer on our site we should be given this chance.
Now, I use both sites very actively, and I don't want to cause any strife or leave behind any ill feelings, but I'm wondering if we should formally approach their moderation corps with a request to consider offering us questions that seem to be more cognitive than not (and of course, we would promise to do the same for any questions that boil down to biochemistry or cell biology, as we've done in the past).  Perhaps a FAQ entry on their end might be warranted, and one on ours as our policies continue to come to fruition.
